# NFS subdirectories offered by Ubuntu cannot be read

Tags: server, mount, nfs, client

FACTS

A previously-working /etc/exports file, running perfectly on Debian, fails to work as expected on Ubuntu. I can export a top-level directory; clients can mount it and see one directory level down; but they are unable to see other subdirectories, and they cannot mount subdirectories.

DISCUSSION

First, something that works just a bit:

```
/archive 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(fsid=root,crossmnt,rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

The fsid=root is mandatory, apparently -- not so on Debian -- and `crossmnt` is there for testing.

I can mount /archive on a client. I can descend to /archive/dir1. However, when clients try to read the directory /archive/dir1, the directory shows as empty.

Next I try a two-line version of /etc/exports:

```
/archive 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(fsid=root,crossmnt,rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/archive/dir1/dir2/dir3 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

The first line is the same as previously, and the 2nd line exports a subdirectory as a separate entity. Again, this works just fine when exported from Debian.

At this point, any attempt to mount /archive/dir1/dir2/dir3 fails. On a Debian client, the client attempts to use NFS version 4.2, complaints of a stale file handle, falls back to version 3, and cycles on version 3 endlessly.

On an Ubuntu client, an attempt to mount fails with "Stale file handle" using NFS version 4; falls back to version 3 and cycles between protocols 6 and 17; and eventually fails.

Please note:
 * All clients are behind the same firewall
 * No machine is running an internal firewall (e.g., ufw is disabled or off)

rpcinfo on the server:

```
# rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  51505  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  33248  mountd
    100005    2   udp  59490  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  46113  mountd
    100005    3   udp  59750  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  38367  mountd
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  55501  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  55501  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  55501  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  37597  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  37597  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  37597  nlockmgr
```

rpcinfo on the client:

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  56523  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  56523  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  56523  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  37425  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  37425  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  37425  nlockmgr
    100024    1   udp  39290  status
    100024    1   tcp  37851  status
    100005    1   udp  52528  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  43547  mountd
    100005    2   udp  36593  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  34609  mountd
    100005    3   udp  42349  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  45613  mountd
```

Finally,

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"
```

in /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server

**EDIT**

A possible symptom is that /var/lib/nfs/rmtab is not up to date. I expect when nfs-kernel-server is stopped, rmtab would be updated; or when I unexport the filesystems (exportfs -ua); or when I unmount at the client. Instead, rmtab continues to maintain the stale information.

ACTIONS

I'd like suggestions on how to debug this problem.

**EDIT 2**

A few more points:

1. I've checked the ACLs (none set) and the file permissions, and they appear to be correct.
2. Even after a cold shutdown of both client and server, done for other reasons, I still get "stale file handle" errors.
3. If I enable rpcdebug to look for NFS proc, I see a complaint about

   no callback path to client Linux NFSv4.2

but that error does not appear for, e.g., MacOS or Ubuntu clients.

4. I have experimented with absolutely minimalist /etc/exports, but none work. For example,

   /something   *(sync,no_subtree_check)

does not work.

Summary: this problem remains intractable, and IMO it's not a simple permissions problem -- unless I'm missing a setting somewhere, or even an entire program or configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive trial and error, I discovered what appears to be the reason for the failure. Looking at `/archive`, I noticed I had a subdirectory of the same name, that is, there was a `/archive/arhive`.

When I deleted the `/archive/archive` my problems stopped for the most part. Based on contents and of permissions of what I saw, the export of `/archive` was actually exporting `/archive/archive`.

Going a bit further: I've noticed that when I export `/archive` the client mounts as NFS version 4. When I mount a subdirectory, namely `/archive/dir1/dir2/dir3`, that subdirectory (same drive and therefor same filesystem) mounts as version 3! I'm still chasing this down, but in the mean time I am up and running.

If this "subdirectory with same name causes bad mount" requires a bug report, I can reproduce this at will and write one up.